# How to achieve hot-reload and non-blocking request in Spring

Tags: spring

The following makes the difference of Spring Framework with Play framework. Play framework has the following

1. Hot reload
2. Non Blocking I/O

Is it possible to achieve the two items in Spring ?

Tomcat is a blocking I/O and not sure whether any new versions planned with non blocking i/o

Thanks

Comment: 1. Use devtools, 2. use reactive.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please share a good link which connected with devtools or reactive for spring? Because of this, the popularity of the play framework goes down?

Comment: Check the regular Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you refer to this - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-async-vs-webflux?

Comment: No to [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)... Not some random tutorial.